# Reading a large log file in C#

Tags: c#, streamreader, logfiles

For my project, I need to extract message types from a log file. I have a 700 MB log file which contains about 4.7 million lines and I need to read each entry line by line and extract the message field. I need to find the size of message in each entry(which is the event size) and store it along with that message in a dictionary. There can be multiple messages for same event size. But I get a OutOfMemoryException when I use the below logic.

```
Dictionary<Int32,List<String>> dt=new Dictionary<Int32,List<String>>();
List<String> entries=new List<String>();
StreamReader sr=new StreamReader("Bluegene.log");
String s;
while((s=sr.readLine())!=null)
{
    eventsize=s.length - 9; //size of only the message field
    entries.Add(s);
    if (!dt.ContainsKey(eventsize))
    {
        dt.Add(eventsize, entries);
    }
    else
    {
       dt.Remove(eventsize);
       dt.Add(eventsize, entries);
     }
  }
```

Will using MemoryMappedFile help?

Comment: How will you be accessing the data? You need to pull all the events with a particular size and work on them based on that?

Comment: Each time you add a entry, you are adding all previous entries in  the List, is that required?

Comment: @user814064 I have the raw log file(.log) with me. I want to read it line by line and form partitions of messages with same size.

Comment: Why do you want to put all that information in a Dictionary?  What are you going to do with it?

Comment: @Steve I have to perform a 3-way partitioning step by step based on 3 heuristics (event size, token position and bijection). Basically I am treating the each entry of the dictionary as a partition.

Comment: Have you considered using a database instead of an in-memory list?

Comment: If you find answer is correct, Please accept it so that it can help other users in future and it is least you can do for someone spend efforts in it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your list is ever growing.

So, you can try the following:

```
Dictionary<Int32, List<String>> dt = new Dictionary<Int32, List<String>>();           
            int eventsize;
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("Bluegene.log");           
            string s;
            while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                eventsize = s.Length - 9; //size of only the message field      
                if (!dt.ContainsKey(eventsize))
                {
                    List<String> entries = new List<String>();
                    entries.Add(s);
                    dt.Add(eventsize, entries);
                }
                else
                {
                    dt[eventsize].Add(s);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thanks Dear developer :)